# How to use GPLv3 in open source project?

Tags: licensing, gpl, gpl-3

I want to use license GPLv3 in my open source project on GitHub. And I want to ask *how can I do that*?
I have read an [article](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.en.html) and I have understood that:

1. My repo has to have a file `License`, that contains information about GPLv3.
2. At the beginning of each project file should be the following text:

> One line to give the program's name and a brief idea of what it does.
>   Copyright (C) `year` `name of author`
>
> This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
>   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
>   (at your option) any later version.
>
> This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
>   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
>   GNU General Public License for more details.
>
> You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>   along with this program.  If not, see https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

**And now I want to ask experts**: Have I understood correctly how to use GPLv3 in my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's not much of an answer, but yes: it seems to me you have done your research carefully and understood the process well.  The only change I would make is that the file `LICENCE` (or `License`, or similar) should contain the full text of GPLv3, rather than information about it.  But other than that, I think you've got it.